# Pass data from file js to other using localStorage

Tags: javascript, json, object, local-storage

I have in the first file.js

```
map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {
  drawnItems.addLayer(e.layer);
  var collection = drawnItems.toGeoJSON();
  localStorage.setItem('gameStorage', JSON.stringify(collection));
});
```

When I want to get the value for localstorage in the second file2.js

```
    var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('gameStorage'));
    var m1 = L.marker([longitude_x, latitude_y]); 
    var polygon = L.polygon(obj.features[0].geometry.coordinates, {
      weight: 1,
      fillOpacity: 0.7,
      color: 'red',
      dashArray: '3'
    });

console.log(polygon.contains(m1.getLatLng()))
```

I got `null` . How I can resolve it , any idea please

Comment: Without any context it's difficult to help, but looks like a loading/execution race condition.

Comment: What is `collection`? I'm assuming you're doing something before saving it to localstorage. And that's where the issue lies. Because you're calling `file2` and trying to get data from localstorage before it's been saved there by `file1`. Edit: your question formatting left out a bunch of relevant code.

Comment: Also it's not clear what `toGeoJSON` is, but if it's [this one](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.toGeoJson) it doesn't return anything anyway; you'd need to set `localStorage` in the callback, which means you'll still have a race condition.

Comment: I use leaflet map . I tested if polygone contains point